# how to transfer binary data through tcpip in matlab

Tags: matlab, tcp, fread

I have read the sample provided by Matlab. My code is

Client:

```
data = single(1024);
t = tcpip('127.0.0.1', 2688, 'NetworkRole', 'Client');
set(t,'Terminator','');
fopen(t);
pause(0.1)
fwrite(t, data, 'float32');
fclose(t);
```

Server:

```
t = tcpip('0.0.0.0', 2688, 'NetworkRole', 'Server');
set(t,'inputbuffersize',4096);
set(t,'Terminator','');

fopen(t);
while t.BytesAvailable==0
    pause(0.1);
    disp('no data');
end
data = fread(t, 1,'float32')
whos data
```

The output is

```
data =

        1024

Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

data      1x1                 8  double
```

It seems that data is with correct value but incorrect type.
The documentation of fread says:

```
 ...By default, numeric values are returned in double-precision arrays...
```

I just want to ask if there is any efficient way to change the type of return array to its true type instead of converting it with something like "single(..)".